# Not reusing output tabs in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I want to run an application several times under different parameter settings, simultaneously. Is there any way to tell PyCharm not to reuse previous output tabs (in order to be able to see the results of the previous runs)? If not, at least, is it possible to tell it to reuse the least recently used tab?

Answer (score 2):

You can pin a tab. Once it's been pinned, the next `run` command will run in new tab. [Documentation here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-tool-window.html)